# Javascript complete form if msgbox answer is YES

Tags: javascript, html

here is a part of  result from a query...

```
`Echo '<input type="text" name="amount" style="height:10px;width:15px;font-size:8px;"    value="1">
<input type="submit" style="height:10px;font-size:6px;" value="Xx"    onclick="confirmDeletec(\'items.php?del='.$item['Idi'].'&nr=1\')">'; `
```

here is javascript function

```
   function confirmDeletec(delUrl3) {
     if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete that item?")) {
      document.location = delUrl3;
     }
     }
```

When i click the button it asks if i want do delete that item and if i press yes it will delete 1 from the total amount of it...

Now the question is how do i make nr=textbox value(eg: items.php?del=43&nr=5 where textboxvalue is 5...)  and then ask if i want to delete...

i tried to make a form but i can-t use the function confirmdelete...

i mention for each mysql result i have a textbox and a submit button...

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JS solution**

Change

```
onclick="confirmDeletec(
```

to

```
onclick="return confirmDeletec(
```

Now change function to

```
function confirmDeletec(delUrl3) {
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete that item?")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you can use JQuery, use following code in place of function

```
$("#formid").submit(function(e){
    if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete that item?")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: my issue is how to delete a certain amount of an item using a texbox for the amount and a button for submitibg the form or a link.php?itemid&nr=textbox.value